# Do you know where I am?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My prefix is under the earth.
>   My infix is under the sea.
>   My suffix is created by [Chuck Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Jones)
>   My adjective is at the end.

**Where am I?**

Comment: I sang this in my head to the tune of "My Bonnie Lies Over the Ocean".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are in

> Helsinki

My prefix is under the earth.

> [Hel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hel_(location)), the underworld realm of the dead.

My infix is under the sea.

> Sink

My suffix is created by Chuck Jones

> [Inki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inki)

My adjective is at the end.

> Finnish (sounds like finish)

Comment: We've got a winner!